# WebpackでSlick.jsを使用する際に、"slick-theme.scss"内で使用されている画像とフォントが読み込めない

Tags: webpack, slick.js

#### 内容

WebpackでjQueryのスライダー用ライブラリSlickを使用しているのですが、
slick-theme.scssをimportするとscss内で定義されている画像とフォントのパスが
localhostのドキュメントルートからのパスになってしまい404 Not Foundとなってしまいます。

現状回避策として、htmlファイルに直接書きを記述することでslick-theme.cssのみWeb上から読み込んでいる状態です。

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick-theme.css"/>
```

#### ディレクトリ構造

```
[ProjectDirectory]
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── commons.js
│   ├── entry.js
│   ├── detail
│   │   └── 1.html
│   └── js
│       └── ①detail.js(この中でslickをimport)
├── src
│   ├── entry.js
│   └── js
│       ├── _common.js
│       ├── detail.js
│       └── list.js
└── ②webpack.config.babel.js
```

##### ①detail.js

```
// <[slick読み込み]===============================>
import 'slick-carousel';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss';

// <[slickerの設定]>============================>
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: true,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '150px',
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 767,
      settings: {
        centerMode: false
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

##### ②webpack.config.js

```
'use strict';
// <[Origin]==================================>
const
webpack = require('webpack'),
path = require('path'),
autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
precss = require('precss')

// <[Paths]==================================>
const
src_path = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
dist_path = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')

// <[Plugins]==================================>
const
CommonsChunkPlugin = new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'commons',
  filename: 'commons.js'
}),
jQuery = new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
}),
NamedModulesPlugin = new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
HotModuleReplacementPlugin = new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
LoaderOptionsPlugin = new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
  options: {
    postcss: [
      require('autoprefixer')({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
      })
    ]
  }
})

// <[ModuleRules]=============================>
const
LOADER_ES6 = {
  test: /\.js$/,
  include: src_path,
  use: [{
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: [
        ['es2015', {modules: false}]
      ]
    }
  }]
},
LOADER_SCSS = {
  test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
  loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?-url', 'sass-loader', 'postcss-loader']
},
LOADER_OTHERS = {
  test: /\.(eot|svg|woff|ttf|gif)$/,
  loader: 'url-loader'
}


// <[CoreConfigs]=============================>
const
config = {
  context: src_path,
  entry: {
    'entry': './entry.js',
    'js/list': './js/list.js',
    'js/detail': './js/detail.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: dist_path,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      LOADER_ES6,
      LOADER_SCSS,
      LOADER_OTHERS
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    jQuery,
    NamedModulesPlugin,
    HotModuleReplacementPlugin,
    CommonsChunkPlugin,
    LoaderOptionsPlugin
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: dist_path,
    port: 8080,
    inline: true,
    hot: true
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

#### ブラウザで表示されるエラーログ

```
http://localhost:8080/detail/ajax-loader.gif 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8080/detail/fonts/slick.woff
http://localhost:8080/detail/fonts/slick.ttf
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/89907

Answer (score 1):

slick-theme.scssファイル内で以下のパスが設定されているので、`/detail`からの相対パスになってしまっているようです。

```
$slick-font-path: "./fonts/" !default;
$slick-loader-path: "./" !default;
```

私のプロジェクトではscssからslickのスタイルをimportをしているのですが、そこでfile-pathを設定しています。

```
// プロジェクト内のscss
$slick-font-path: "~slick-carousel/slick/fonts/";
$slick-loader-path: "~slick-carousel/slick/";
@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss";
@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss";
```

Comment: Nozomiさん
ご回答頂きありがとうございます。

scssでimportする方法に変更し、
頂いたようにdefaultのパスを明示的に設定してみたのですが、
下記パスでNot foundとなってしまいます。

http://localhost:8080/detail/~slick-carousel/slick/ajax-loader.gif
http://localhost:8080/detail/~slick-carousel/slick/fonts/slick.ttf 
http://localhost:8080/detail/~slick-carousel/slick/fonts/slick.woff 

重ね重ねで恐縮ですが、
何か分かりましたらご教授頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: cssファイルのビルドと、そのビルドされたcssのimportはどのようにしていますか？ "defaultのパスを明示的に設定"している方法＆場所を教えてください。